# replicate lazy loaded angular tab pages

Tags: angular, tabs, lazy-loading, code-reuse

I followed angular lazy loaded tab modules pages [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)  to create tabs. but I have a base  component that needs to be replicated on 7 really similar tabs with few things changes give or take. in order to avoid code duplication I have a base component and tested it on one of the module and it works fine.

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar class="optiontabs">
    <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let option of options"
    [routerLink]="option.theroute"
    routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
    [active]="rla.isActive">{{option.label}}</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>


  options = [{
  label: "option1",
  theroute: "option1",
},
...]
```

inside option1 routing module I  called basecomponent to test and it works

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '',component: baseComponent }, ];
```

the base component has it's own css, html and ts files. it's html is a compose of multiple apps that look something like this:

```
<div class="summary-option-container">

    <app-template-table ></app-template-table>   
    <app-optiondetails></app-optiondetails>
    <app-chart></app-chart>
...
</div>
```

how do I replicate the base component across the various options tabs? originally I thought I could just extends it. but the html and css would need to be redone in each 7 option modules so no.
I looked into using `<ng-template matTabContent>` as described in [material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) but doesn't give me routing for each options so it's not quite what I want since later down the line I need to add params to the options urls so I can have [www.blabla.com/option1/xyz](http://www.blabla.com/option1/xyz). I am not really sure on composition either. how do I make this work?

Comment: Have you tried using BaseComponent with content projection? I mean if those 7 tabs (or pages) share the same layout (BaseComponent) you could define those 7 components in the routes and render the BaseComponent inside them, then you could make BaseComponent configurable using `@Input`s and `ng-content`

Comment: If you need further help for a specific scenario I suggest you to create a minimal reproducible example in a platform like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and share the link here.

Comment: @MauroAguilar no not yet.  I'd look into it